# How to display total count in descending order but group by id

Tags: sql

i have the following codes which displays the following result

```
select distinct 
      srcaccountid,
      srccharid,
      srccharname,
      action, 
      itemname, 
      sum(itemcount) over (partition by srccharname, itemname) 
         as total_count, 
      sum(price) over(partition by srccharname, itemname) 
         as total_price 
   from 
      itemlog
   where 
          action = 6 
      and logtime >='2023-02-13'
   order by 
      total_count desc, 
      srcaccountid
```

the result is as follows

```
srcaccountid  srccharid  srccharname  action  itemname  total_count  total_price
1             21         abc          6       dog       2222         231
2             22         sdd          6       cat       1234         122
1             21         abc          6       cat        324          77
1             21         abc          6       mouse      122          32
2             22         sdd          6       mouse       12           3
```

i will like the result to show as follow

```
srcaccountid  srccharid  srccharname  action  itemname  total_count 
 total_price
1             21         abc          6       dog       2222         231
1             21         abc          6       cat        324         77
1             21         abc          6       mouse      122         32
2             22         sdd          6       cat       1234         122
2             22         sdd          6       mouse       12         3
```

i cant seem to be able to show the highest sales amount while grouping the ids together and not splitting them up

Answer (score 0):

Change the order by. Put the srcaccountid first.

```
order by 
   srcaccountid,
   total_count desc
```